# Laravel 5/Sentry 2 - Session Not Pertaining Accross Domain/subdomain

Tags: session, laravel-5

In laravel 4.1:
In file /app/config/session.php, When i gave domain => 'domain.com'
session could be access all over the sub and main domain. 
means, session can be readable in domain.com or user1.domain.com or user2.domain.com.

But in Laravel 5.0:
session no pretaining accorss domain. 
Session set in user1.domain.com not able to read in user2.domain.com.

In file /config/session.php, When i gave domain => '.domain.com'
But still its not working..

Could you please help me to solve the issue.?

Comment: When you changed it to `'.domain.com'`, did you clear the cookies after?

Comment: Yes i cleared cookies, but its not working.

Comment: I have worked two sites in Laravel 4.1, session pretain in subdomains. 
But I'm facing this issue in Laravel 5.0. 
In file /config/session.php,
domain => '.domain.com',  // 'domain.com'   '*.domain.com',
'driver' => 'database'   // 'file'
Nothing worked.. 
help me to solve the issue

Comment: does anyone have an idea about this issue?